# Integer division by zero

Tags: c++, integer-division

The error returned is "Unhandled exception at 0x01355144 in Homework_3_Problem_15.exe: 0xC0000094: Integer division by zero."

I can see that the variable 'greatestCommonDivisor' is being assigned a value of 0, but I can't figure out why.

Here's my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int greatestCommonDivisor;

void inputNumbers(int& numerator, int& denominator);
int convertToGreatestCommonDivisor(int numerator, int denominator);
void convertToLowestTerms(int& numerator, int& denominator);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int numerator = 1;
    int denominator = 1;

    inputNumbers(numerator, denominator);
    convertToGreatestCommonDivisor(numerator, denominator);
    convertToLowestTerms(numerator, denominator);

    return 0;
}

void inputNumbers(int& numerator, int& denominator)
{
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "Please enter the numerator: ";
    cin >> numerator;
    cout << "Please enter the denominator: ";
    cin >> denominator;
    cout << "\n";
    return;
}

int convertToGreatestCommonDivisor(int numerator, int denominator)
{
    int greatestCommonDivisor;
    int i;
    // checks if i is greater than the numerator *and* the denominator
    for (i = 1; i <= numerator && i <= denominator; i++)
    {
        if (numerator % i == 0 && denominator % i == 0)
        {
            greatestCommonDivisor = i;
        }
    }
    return (greatestCommonDivisor);
}

void convertToLowestTerms(int& numerator, int& denominator)
{
    cout << "The fraction " << numerator << " / " << denominator << " reduces to " <<
    (numerator / greatestCommonDivisor) << " / " << (denominator / greatestCommonDivisor);
}
```

Any help you can give would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please use a debugger first, to find where and why the problem occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `greatestCommonDivisor` is global, simply you can change your `convertToGreatestCommonDivisor` function to

```
void convertToGreatestCommonDivisor(int numerator, int denominator)  //Change return type to void
{
    // Remove the local variable "greatestCommonDivisor"
    int i;
    // checks if i is greater than the numerator *and* the denominator
    for (i = 1; i <= numerator && i <= denominator; i++)
    {
        if (numerator % i == 0 && denominator % i == 0)
        {
            greatestCommonDivisor = i;
        }
    }
    //Remove the return statement
}
```

Comment: @user3654700, I highly recommend getting rid of the global variable.

Comment: @Elizabeth; I glad that it helped you :). By the way `Elizabeth` is much better than `user3654700` :D

Comment: @chris; Agreed. But when program runs successfully without changing much to it then the happiness becomes double for a newbie :)

Comment: @haccks, And then there's the skill everyone should acquire of writing a bunch of code and then later throwing it away without being attached to it. Kind of makes it seem a bit heartless when it's put like that.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to misunderstand how returning from a function works.

In `convertToGreatestCommonDivisor`, you have a local variable called `greatestCommonDivisor`. You assign some values to this and then `return` it. When you call `convertToGreatestCommonDivisor(numerator, denominator);`, you are ignoring this return value.

Then, `convertToLowestTerms` uses the global variable `greatestCommonDivisor` that is declared on line 5. This variable has value 0.

It looks like you probably want to store the value returned from `convertToGreatestCommonDivisor` and then pass it to `convertToLowestTerms`:

```
int greatestCommonDivisor = convertToGreatestCommonDivisor(numerator, denominator);
convertToLowestTerms(greatestCommonDivisor, numerator, denominator);
```

This requires adding an additional parameter to `convertToLowestTerms`. The global variable is not necessary at all.

Answer (score 1):

```
int greatestCommonDivisor;
```

Is global and if uninitialized, is automatically equal to `0`. I think you meant to do this:

```
greatestComonDivisor = convertToGreatestCommonDivisor(numerator, denominator);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 `greatestCommonDivisor` variables one is global one is local. Global one is always 0,undefined or holds some random value depending on your environment build type etc.

Comment: Global variables are zero-initialized. If they aren't, the compiler has a bug.